# Dynamic query execute in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to generate a dynamic SQL command stored in a LongText that will be executed in a stored procedure.

The code for the stored procedure looks like this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test.Dquery()
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE test.Dquery()
BEGIN

DECLARE EXEC LONGTEXT DEFAULT '';

SET EXEC = CONCAT(
'
SELECT * FROM test.customers LIMIT 5;
'); 

PREPARE stmt FROM @EXEC; 
EXECUTE stmt; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Getting an error in execution... Any ideas?

Comment: You do not need `DECLARE EXEC LONGTEXT DEFAULT '';` you can directly set the value as `@qry = concat('select.....')` and use `@qry` in prepared statement.